# Symfony3 + FPDF - return response in new window.

Tags: symfony, fpdf, symfony3.x

In Symfony3, I want to use [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) to generate a pdf output. It's OK but my problem is that this output is on the current tab. I would like this output opens a new tab and appears in it. I tested pdf output this way :

```
public function testAction(request $request)
{
    $pdf = new \FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
    $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
    $pdf->Multicell(190, 5, "Hello World!", '', 'C', false);
    return new Response($pdf->Output(), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/pdf'));
}
```

Thank you to help me solving this teasing problem !

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it on the server side (by using PHP), but if you're using a form for calling this action you could set `target=__blank` and it'll do the job. You can also achieve this result by using js (e.g. you're using `ajax`).